# how to map VimroomToggle to several actions

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I write blog articles in vim, markdown format. I want to use the awesome "Vimroom" plugin for vim. But the plugin doesn't do several things:

1. It does not unset the line numbers
2. it does not unset the colorcolumn

And I want it to do that stuff if I write a blog article.

Currently I would have to do:

```
:VimroomToggle
:set nonumber
:set cc=''
```

I cannot use :setlocal, because it (Vimroom) generates several Buffers for showing the write buffer in the middle of the screen, and these other buffers have line numbers, too.

I'm not a advanced vimscript writer, so please could you help me and explain, what you're doing there?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write a script for that. Adding this line to your `~/.vimrc` should do the trick.

```
nnoremap <leader>v :VimroomToggle \| set nonumber cc=''<cr>
```

Now, when you want to write a blog post, you just have to hit `<leader>v`. Read `:h mapleader` for more information about `<leader>`. You can devise your own shortcut, of course.

If you want *all* your markdown files to come without `number` and `colorcolumn`, you could add this line to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd FileType markdown :setlocal nonumber cc=''
```

Comment: I don't think that's sufficient here, because (as stated in the question), VimRoom creates multiple _padding windows_ around the actual window, and these should have the settings turned off, too.

Comment: Aren't those other windows supposed to be empty? Removing line numbering in them as well kind of makes sense to me. I haven't any experience with that plugin, though.

Comment: Yes, they are. But you'd have to do the `:set` _before_ enabling VimRoom, not after it, because the change won't affect the already opened windows. (Only `:windo`, as suggested by Daan, would.)

Answer (score 0):

`setlocal` doesn't do anything different than `set` for `number` and `cc`. That's because they are window variables. If you switch to another buffer the `cc` and `number` settings remain the same. Also, if you have 2 windows open, setting `cc` or `number` will only change one of them.

What you can do though is use the `windo` command, for example:

```
nnoremap <F2> :windo :set nonu cc=""<cr>
nnoremap <F3> :windo :set nu cc=+1<cr>
```

Will change the `nu` and `cc` for all windows. I would not recommend using an autocommand for that, because if you switch to another buffer in the same window it will have the same settings.